# How to complete a recommendation - 'An Azure Active Directory administrator should be provisioned for SQL servers' sent by Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, active-directory

We have a SQL database located in Azure. We got a recommendation from Microsoft Azure saying to provision Active Directory administrator for SQL servers. When I log into Azure portal, I'm able to see a default active directory.

[image]

I'm not familiar with Active Directory. I referred this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure but I'm not getting the exact steps to follow the recommendation.

**EDIT1** This is the Active Directory admin page we could see.

[image]

**EDIT2** Users list page in the Default Directory

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It refers to the AAD integration of Azure SQL DB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication

Doing this, you can for many scenarios get rid of extra logins and password for SQL and instead use SSO with Azure AD and things like MFA.

Comment: Thanks @silent. I referred the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure to add an admin user to default directory. But I am not able to add it as guest account is not supported and we do not have any user when I see 'Active Directory admin' page.

Comment: well in this case I guess there is nothing for you to do but to suspend the recommendation

Comment: okay. Can we add a user and then assign him/her an admin for Active Directory? I updated the question to include users list page. Please have a look at it.

Comment: But the problem is, I am not able to add a user which is not a guest.

Comment: I guess you’ve reached an impasse then :(

Answer (score 0):

This [ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell) includes a script that can be run in powershell to provision the user for AAD.

1) In the Azure portal, in the upper-right corner, select your connection to drop down a list of possible Active Directories.

2) Choose the correct Active Directory as the default Azure AD.

- This step links the subscription associated with Active Directory
  with Managed Instance making sure that the same subscription is used
  for both Azure AD and the Managed Instance.

3)Navigate to Managed Instance and select one that you want to use for Azure AD integration.

[image]

4) Select the banner on top of the Active Directory admin page and grant permission to the current user. If you're logged in as Global/Company administrator in Azure AD, you can do it from the Azure portal or using PowerShell with the script below.  Grant permissions-portal

[image]

Here is the Powershell script:

```
   # Gives Azure Active Directory read permission to a Service Principal representing the managed instance.
    # Can be executed only by a "Company Administrator", "Global Administrator", or "Privileged Role Administrator" type of user.

    $aadTenant = "<YourTenantId>" # Enter your tenant ID $managedInstanceName = "MyManagedInstance"

    # Get Azure AD role "Directory Users" and create if it doesn't exist $roleName = "Directory Readers" $role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq $roleName} if ($role -eq $null) {
        # Instantiate an instance of the role template
        $roleTemplate = Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleTemplate | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq $roleName}
        Enable-AzureADDirectoryRole -RoleTemplateId $roleTemplate.ObjectId
        $role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq $roleName} }

    # Get service principal for managed instance $roleMember = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString $managedInstanceName $roleMember.Count if ($roleMember -eq $null) {
        Write-Output "Error: No Service Principals with name '$    ($managedInstanceName)', make sure that managedInstanceName parameter was     entered correctly."
        exit } if (-not ($roleMember.Count -eq 1)) {
        Write-Output "Error: More than one service principal with name pattern '$    ($managedInstanceName)'"
        Write-Output "Dumping selected service principals...."
        $roleMember
        exit }

    # Check if service principal is already member of readers role $allDirReaders = Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId $selDirReader = $allDirReaders | where{$_.ObjectId
    -match     $roleMember.ObjectId}

    if ($selDirReader -eq $null) {
        # Add principal to readers role
        Write-Output "Adding service principal '$($managedInstanceName)' to     'Directory Readers' role'..."
        Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId -RefObjectId     $roleMember.ObjectId
        Write-Output "'$($managedInstanceName)' service principal added to     'Directory Readers' role'..."

        #Write-Output "Dumping service principal '$($managedInstanceName)':"
        #$allDirReaders = Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId
        #$allDirReaders | where{$_.ObjectId -match $roleMember.ObjectId} }

else {
    Write-Output "Service principal '$($managedInstanceName)' is already     member of 'Directory Readers' role'."
}
```

5)After the operation is successfully completed, the following notification will show up in the top-right corner:

[image]

6) Now you can choose your Azure AD admin for your managed instance. For that, on the Active Directory admin page, select Set admin command.

[image]

I will try this tomorrow, but if you get to it, let me know how it goes. Good luck.